# trying to remove a child from div a second time ( javascript)

Tags: javascript

I tried to remove a child element a second time using js but I get an error message (Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
    at SwitchForThirdSlide)

The div, obtainImgDiv contains an img with id , getImageId which I'm trying to remove and replace everytime a button is pressed. I tried using a setTimeout method for the second function in the event listener but it still gives the same error.

```
var getImageId = document.getElementById("cat");

var obtainImgDiv = document.getElementById("images4slideshow");

function SwitchForSecondSlide(getImageId,obtainImgDiv) {
    obtainImgDiv.removeChild(getImageId);

    var newImg = document.createElement("img");

    newImg.setAttribute("id", "cat");
    newImg.setAttribute("src", "Images/cat2.jpg");
    newImg.setAttribute("class", "cat");

    obtainImgDiv.appendChild(newImg);
}

slideShowButton2.addEventListener("click",  function  () {
    SwitchForSecondSlide(getImageId,obtainImgDiv);
}, false);

function SwitchForThirdSlide(getImageId,obtainImgDiv) {
   obtainImgDiv.removeChild(getImageId);  
}

slideShowButton3.addEventListener("click", function() {
    SwitchForThirdSlide(getImageId,obtainImgDiv);
},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The newly created image `var newImg = document.createElement("img");` is not set to your `obtainImgDiv`. `obtainImgDiv` is executed only once during the starup and so it still contains the old child, you can simply replace the global variable(easiest change)

Instead of `var newImg = document.createElement("img");, you can try`obtainImgDiv = document.createElement("img"); and change other statements containing `newImage` variable to `obtainImgDiv`

Comment: I tried appending the new image in the div 'obtainImgDiv.appendChild(newImg);'

Comment: `obtainImgDiv` is someething you remove on the first line, and if you try to append to a removed child which is not present in the DOM, then would be child be in the DOM ???

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying that I have to remove `obtainImgDiv` first?